# Spring MVC controller cannot be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I'm working on a Spring MVC project, have a controller working fine but suddenly doesn't work. Keep throwing 404 error when I hit the url that the controller should have handled.

For my controller class, below is a snippet of my controller class:
    package mywebapp.controller;

```
import java.util.*;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import mywebapp.dao.model.interfaces.PetDao;
import mywebapp.model.Pet;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class PetController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PetController.class);

    public static Logger getLog() {
        return LOG;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("PetDaoJpaImpl")
    private PetDao petDao;

    public PetDao getPetDao() {
        return petDao;
    }

    public void setPetDao(PetDao petDao) {
        this.petDao = petDao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "pet.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAllPets() throws Exception {
        getLog().info("Activating controller........");
        List<Pet> petList = getPetDao().getAllPets();
        getLog().info("Getting name in nameList......");
        return new ModelAndView("petInfo", "petList", petList);
    }
}
```

It should map a "pet.htm" url, but when i hit this url it gives me:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MyWebapp/pet.htm

type Status report

message /MyWebapp/pet.htm

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
```

And there is no error stack in my console. Anyone have similar issue? Any help will be appreciated.

FYI, here is my Application Context file, I use java to configure the dispatcher servlet:

```
package mywebapp.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class SpringAppContext implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MywebappConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(MywebappConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

==============================**UPDATE**=========================================

MywebappConfig.java:

```
package mywebapp.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import mywebapp.controller.PetController;
import mywebapp.dao.model.impl.PetDaoJdbcImpl;
import mywebapp.dao.model.impl.PetDaoJpaImpl;
import mywebapp.dao.model.interfaces.PetDao;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mywebapp")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MywebappConfig {

    Properties getProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "getDataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pet");
        datasource.setUsername("admin");
        datasource.setPassword("admin");
        return datasource;
    }

    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "mywebapp.model" });
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(getProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getView() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver view = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        view.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        view.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        view.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return view;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

=====================================**UPDATE**==================================
Console Log when server start:

```
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyWebapp' did not find a matching property.
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 7 2015 13:07:11 UTC
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.67.0
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_71-b15
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Guanlun.Mu\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.67
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Guanlun.Mu\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.67
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Guanlun.Mu\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\endorsed
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\gradle-2.10\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\Guanlun.Mu\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.2.RELEASE;;.
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1455 ms
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:52 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [165] milliseconds.
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 04, 2016 1:02:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3218 ms
```

Comment: Please provide MywebappConfig class as well

Comment: Have you tried to add the slash `(value=/pet.htm)`  in the request mapping value? And typed in the context name in small letters?

Comment: Also exclude the `.htm` from the URL and the request mapping value and try.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale Added

Comment: @Lucky I tried all of those, they don't work. Actually it was working fine yesterday and I have no idea what I did today to make it doesn't work...

Comment: Config looks fine to me. Does your application start fine? Do you see in the logs all controllers registered? You see log like RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/pet.htm],methods=[GET]

Comment: OK @ODStreet . In your dispatcher servlet change the mapping to *.htm or  simply * and check if any of these work. Currently you have given it / and you are trying *.htm. So it won't work obviously.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale yeah, the application starts fine, showing index.jsp and all the static pages. However i didn't see log about controller registration. I will add the log when the server started.

Comment: @Lucky It still doesn't work. The "/" indicate that any url for {baseUrl}/{anything} will be mapped. So having a "/" in dispatcher servlet is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows this

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

Your web application is not deployed. Could you ensure your project compiled fine and the `SpringAppContext` class exists in your war.

Comment: I think you're right, i compile the project in my terminal and it throws a compilation error. I guess I messed up the classpath this morning.